# Unable to run my codes to make NAO move

Tags: python, python-2.7, nao-robot

I have create a simple code using Python SDK version 2.7. I am trying to connect it to the simulated robot in choregraphe but the codes are unable to run with this error.

This is my codes:

```
from naoqi import ALProxy
motion = ALProxy("ALMotion", "127.0.0.1", 9559)
motion.moveInit()
motion.moveTo(0.5, 0, 0)
```

Here's the error:

[image: Here's the error:]

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost. I.e. your own PC.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean Python 2.7, not the SDK. What Version of Naoqi Python SDK are you using?

Also, what simulated robot are you trying to use? If it is the one included in Choregraphe, you simply can't connected it externally without launching choregraphe. That Simulated robot is initiated at Choregraphe startup.

Answer (score 0):

The error is just that the IP:port is not connecting to any robot.

If you want to connect to:

- the real robot: use the ip of the robot (press the chest button to get it) and port 9559
- the Choregraphe simulated robot: use 127.0.0.1 and check in the Choregraphe connection menu to get the port (for instance I have 58383 right now) as it changes.
- another simulated robot: run naoqi-bin separately, and use 127.0.0.1 and port 9559.